# App Shortcut without pinning to Start Screen in Windows 8 using C++

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-8

Our company has an installer written in C++ that creates program shortcuts using IShellLink as described in:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776891%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

On Windows 8 all shortcuts created in the Start Menu will also show as titles on the Start Screen. What we're looking to do is programmically control which icons are shown on the Start Screen. In the following article it describes the option "System.AppUserModel.StartPinOption" as:

> To create add an app shortcut without pinning it to the Start screen
>   view, you can set the following property on the shortcut:
>   System.AppUserModel.StartPinOption = 1. The symbolic name for 1 is
>   APPUSERMODEL_STARTPINOPTION_NOPINONINSTALL.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/jj673981%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

This appears to be possible using the Windows Installer, however I haven't found a way to accomplish the same functionality programmatically in C++ given our context.

If anyone has any information about this, or an example of some sort, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: The C++ name is [`PKEY_AppUserModel_StartPinOption`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/jj553605%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the response Raymond. Are you aware of any examples of how this is used and at what point in the creation process it should be done? Even summary psuedo code would help.

Comment: You can [adapt this code](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/02/11/10127763.aspx), but instead of setting `PKEY_AppUserModel_ExcludeFromShowInNewInstall` to `VARIANT_TRUE`, you set `PKEY_AppUserModel_StartPinOption` to `APPUSERMODEL_STARTPINOPTION_NOPINONINSTALL`.

Comment: I'll give that a go. Thank you very much Raymond, I appreciate the response and additional info.

Comment: Raymond has also created a full article and sample on this: [Marking a shortcut to say that it should not be placed on the Windows 8 Start page upon installation or treated as a newly-installed application](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/03/04/10398946.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

One thing I found was that "..NewInstall" literally means that.  User customizations to the tiles seem to be retained even after you delete/update the .lnk files.  This is probably a good thing as updates won't reset the user's environment, but it does mean that I needed to use fresh installs of Windows 8 during testing.  I used a VM box to minimize the pain.  At least I don't know how to delete the properties once set from within the environment.

Comment: Deleting and recreating the icon/shortcut file will reset the flags and cause it to be "new" again.

Comment: Tried that many times with no success.  After recreating the shortcuts the tiles appeared as I had left them.  Our QA group found the same thing.  We actually like the behavior.  However, if you're correct then I assume a reboot or re-login is required to flush a cache.