# Unpin from start menu using c# in win8

Tags: c#, windows-8, tile

I am developing a c# desktop application.

We need to unpin our application tile based on number of conditions. this could happen anytime during the application life-cycle, and not only during installation.

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13362685/app-shortcut-without-pinning-to-start-screen-in-windows-8-using-c) question on how to unpin a tile in CPP. I tried to do that also in C# with no success.

any help?

Update:

I was able to write a C# code that sets the AppUserModel_StartPinOption to APPUSERMODEL_STARTPINOPTION_NOPINONINSTALL but it didn't help :(

this is the code:

```
private static void InstallShortcut(string linkPath)
    {

        // Find the path to the current executable
        // String exePath = Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName;  //Path to the current exe file that is running.  C:\\...
        IShellLinkW newShortcut = (IShellLinkW)new CShellLink();

        // Create a shortcut to the exe
        ErrorHelper.VerifySucceeded(newShortcut.SetPath(targetPath));
       ErrorHelper.VerifySucceeded(newShortcut.SetArguments(""));

        // Open the shortcut property store, set the AppUserModelId property
        IPropertyStore newShortcutProperties = (IPropertyStore)newShortcut;


            var APPUSERMODEL_STARTPINOPTION_NOPINONINSTALL = new PropVariant(0);
            var StartPinOption = new PropertyKey(new Guid("{9F4C2855-9F79-4B39-A8D0-E1D42DE1D5F3}"), 12);
            ErrorHelper.VerifySucceeded(newShortcutProperties.SetValue(StartPinOption, APPUSERMODEL_STARTPINOPTION_NOPINONINSTALL));


            ErrorHelper.VerifySucceeded(newShortcutProperties.Commit());


        // Commit the shortcut to disk
        IPersistFile newShortcutSave = (IPersistFile)newShortcut;

        ErrorHelper.VerifySucceeded(newShortcutSave.Save(linkPath, true));
    }
```

I tried both: removing the tile and then recreating it, and changing the params of an existing tile, but nothing worked, the tile stays pinned to the start menu.

Comment: is your application a Windows Store app or a desktop app?  If the former, I don't believe this is possible - it goes against the mantra of the user being in charge of the experience. The sample you saw for C++ is a desktop app.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I am working on a desktop app.

Answer (score 2):

Are you talking about your main application tile or a secondary tile?  If you are referring to a secondary tile, there is sample code for unpinning in [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jennifer/archive/2012/11/19/real-world-secondary-tiles-top-three-tips-for-working-with-secondary-tiles-in-windows-8-apps.aspx).  The meat of it is (and I'm modifying a bit for simplicity; see the article for the full code):

```
 // Check to see if this restaurant exists as a secondary tile and then unpin it
 string restaurantKey = this.m_ViewModel.Restaurant.Key;
 Button button = sender as Button;
 if (button != null)
 {
     if (Windows.UI.StartScreen.SecondaryTile.Exists(restaurantKey))
     {
         SecondaryTile secondaryTile = new SecondaryTile(restaurantKey);
         bool isUnpinned = await secondaryTile.RequestDeleteForSelectionAsync(GetElementRect((FrameworkElement)sender), Windows.UI.Popups.Placement.Above);

         if (!isUnpinned)
         {
             // Do error handling here
         }
     }
     else
     {
         // If we ever get to this point, something went wrong or the user manually 
         // removed the tile from their Start screen.  
         Debug.WriteLine(restaurantKey + " is not currently pinned.");
     }
 }
```

Comment: This code is only for a Metro app (Windows Store app).  Sorry, you hadn't made your comment yet that you were writing a desktop app when I responded.  :(

Answer (score 0):

According to [the MSDN article: System.AppUserModel.StartPinOption (Windows)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/jj553605%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), the No pin install option should be (1)

```
var APPUSERMODEL_STARTPINOPTION_NOPINONINSTALL = new PropVariant(1);
```

I got it working by doing this.